# solana command not found after ubuntu update 22.04 jammy

Tags: ubuntu, solana, solana-cli

No matter how many times I try installing solana-cli and adding the path with

- `PATH="/home/myUserName/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"`
- `export PATH="/home/myUserName/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"`

commands, terminal is not recognizing solana commands after I close the terminal, i.e **path is not persisting**... I tried reinstalling solana-cli but it's not helping...

I need to set path every time I whenever I need to use the cli.

is it a known issue? how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You should have this path set in `/home/yourUserName/.profile`
That way it will not be lost.
But this is done by default by CLI installation so there might be also something else. Open new terminal and type `echo $PATH`, then you will see what your path really is.

Comment: thanks for the initiative riengi! I faced the same issue with anchor-cli/avm, cargo, and other tools I use. I do not know what causes this but what I did was add the path variables manually to my .bashrc file